# "Auto Layout still required" error when adding subview to UITableView only on iOS 7

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, autolayout, autoresizingmask

I have a container which loads an `UITableViewController`. On the beginning there is no data in the table so I show an empty view. This is how I do it in `ViewDidLoad`:

```
emptyView = new UIView ();
emptyView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Gray;
// works on iOS 8 but has to be removed on iOS 7
emptyView.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

var views = NSDictionary.FromObjectsAndKeys(
    new object[] { emptyView },
    new object[] { "emptyView" }
);

View.AddSubview (emptyView);
this.TableView.SeparatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None;

View.AddConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat ("V:|-0-[emptyView]-0-|", NSLayoutFormatOptions.DirectionLeadingToTrailing, null, views));
View.AddConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat ("H:|-0-[emptyView]-0-|", NSLayoutFormatOptions.DirectionLeadingToTrailing, null, views));
```

The problem is now the line where I disable the autoresizing mask. On iOS 7.1 (on device and simulator) I get the following error:

> NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: Auto Layout still required
>   after executing -layoutSubviews. UITableView's implementation of
>   -layoutSubviews needs to call super.

If I comment out `TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` everything works fine. The same code is running without modifications on iOS 8. I only remove the autoresizing mask on my view and not on the whole `UITableView`. Adding the view to the table header leads to the same problem.

How should I solve the problem with Auto Layout? Although the code is in C# you can always provide solutions from the Objective C world because the concepts are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved away from auto layout and I'm not using it anymore for my `emptyView`.

```
emptyView = new UIView (new RectangleF(0, 0, this.View.Bounds.Size.Width, this.View.Bounds.Size.Height));
emptyView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
emptyView.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.All;
```

Now it works, but I don't know if it is intended to not use auto layout. Perhaps one could provide a better answer which I could mark as accepted.